# How to Handle Multiple Git Repositories

Tags: git, bitbucket, versioning

I work on two different, independent systems and we store our code on BitBucket (Git). The two different systems are housed in two different repositories on BitBucket. Let us just call them 'system1' and 'system2'. Each repository follows GitFlow with a master/develop/release branching scheme.

We also have a separate repository that houses a shared library that is used by both 'system1' and 'system2'. There is also another repository that contains all networking-related software that is also used by 'system1' and 'system2'.

The 'system1' and 'system2' repository each has a build script. The build scripts have an expectation that each of the repositories are cloned at the same directory level. So, for example, like this:

```
~/system1
~/system2
~/shared_library
~/networking
```

The build scripts use `git describe` to tag each build. It uses the output of `git describe` in each repository to create a build. So, just as an example, the build information out of `system1` would look like this:

```
SYSTEM1: 10.1.1
SHARED_LIBRARY: 10.1.1
NETWORKING: 10.1.1
```

All of this software is bundled and installed onto the target machine with the SYSTEM1 tag.

The problem I am having is if there is a change in `networking` then that is not reflected in the build number for `system1`. For example, let's say a single commit was made to `networking`. Running the build script now looks like this:

```
SYSTEM1: 10.1.1
SHARED_LIBRARY: 10.1.1
NETWORKING: 10.1.1-1
```

When installed, it still looks like version 10.1.1 even though it is not (because the network has changed).

Essentially, I need to change my scheme so that changes in certain other repositories are reflected in the `git describe` output in `system1`.

I am unsure on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, how about a build-time test that checks for version updates and fails if a dependency (networking) version is updated but dependent (system1) version is not? Then you could at least automatically detect and manually resolve outdated dependent versions. In your example where networking is incremented but system1 is not, when building system1 in such a state, the test would fail and thus so would the build. Depending on your needs, implementing the test might be as simple as checking for the existence of any `-<commits>` (e.g. `-1`) suffix in any dependency. Or as complex as checking your artifact repository for the latest built artifact version. The precise logic is pretty dependent on your environment.

Then as an optional next step, you could move to automate the incrementing of versions altogether. Instead of manually tagging in BitBucket, have the build system (or even just a manually kicked-off but otherwise automated promotion script) increment versions rather than you manually setting them. This automated solution could do things like automatically cascade version increments from dependency (networking) to dependent (system1). You can potentially use this same sort of system to do the tagging automatically, e.g. on a successful build. I've seen portions of this approach used successfully.

There may also be a solution that leverages git more, but one nice thing about automating some of your version checks or increments in your build system is that it can potentially make your pipeline less dependent on your implementation technology choices (e.g. git, npm, specific languages, etc.).

Comment: My understanding was that when you use `git describe` it automatically appends the number of commits since the most recent annotated tag. Your suggestion would be to do away with this altogether and just manually track my build numbers in a script. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: To your very first sentence, it is possible for `networking` to contain new commits but `system1` to not contain any new commits. In essence, a new release of `system1` contains only networking updates. There are no new commits in `system1` so git only sees it as `10.1.1`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can update my answer to incorporate some of those specifics and address some of your questions... One question for you... Where/how do you specify versions today? (What creates the version tags?) I'm familiar for example with versions declared in files like npm package.json or maven pom.xml.

Comment: Short answer to your questions in the above comments is, no, I wasn't intending to suggest you change *how* you version or necessarily generate tags. My answer is intended to be mostly additive to your system, i.e. adding tests (enforcement) and automation.

Comment: Oh one more question, how is a build for system1 triggered? If you don't have this already, I think you may want to consider triggering system1 builds from changes to its dependencies (networking, etc.). That is straightforward in Jenkins and most CI systems.

Comment: Currently, a script called "build_system1" in the top directory of "system1" is executed. This runs a "make" on all of our software and packages the individual software components into their own respective RPMs. It then goes to the "shared_library" repository, builds that RPM, and then goes to the "networking" repository and builds that RPM. It then bundles all of these RPMs and some installation scripts into a tarball. The version tags are created through the BitBucket interface currently (in other words, manually).

Comment: I have only briefly looked into Jenkins but I am under some pretty intense pressure to get this thing off the ground. I will look into Jenkins later to automate this. For now, I am just trying to get a build process to work using multiple repositories. I think what I might do is put a target for 'shared_library' and 'networking' in the 'build_system1.sh' script. So, if something new comes along in 'networking', then 'build_system1.sh' script will need to be updated to include the new target. But, in gitflow, I should be able to just build a branch (release) and not have to worry about tags.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer in attempt to address your comments. Hope it's helpful!